# asymptotic stability with exact feedback and feedback with measurement errors

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

I'm trying to show global asymptotic stability (GAS) for a system with a feedback controller. I managed to show GAS for the perfect feedback signal, that is

$$\gamma(x(t)) = K_p x_1(t) + K_d x_2(t).$$

Now, I'm interested in showing GAS if - like in a real system - I measure $x_1$ and $x_2$ thus introducing uncertainties and compose that to be my feedback signal like
$$ \gamma(x(t),t) = K_p (x_1(t) + \Delta x_1(t)) + K_d (x_2(t) + \Delta x_2(t)).$$

When I try and do the proof as I've done it with the "perfect" signal, when calculation the derivative of the lyapunov function, I no longer have a lyapunov function which only depends on $x$ but also on $t$. This leads to derivatives of the uncertainties $\Delta x_1$ and $\Delta x_2$ which I do not know.

Question is: Are there some kind of standard ways to handle that or to argue that the system is still GAS?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your equilibrium is zero. If so, I highly doubt that you can asymptotically stabilize the system with static state feedback without imposing some assumptions on $\Delta x_1$ and $\Delta x_2$--*I am assuming you have a linear system, and therefore, it is impossible if... let's say $\Delta x_1 = 5$ $\forall~t$*. For instance, you can prove GAS if you assume that 
$$|\Delta x_i| \leq c_i |x_i|$$
for some $c_i \geq 0$ and $i\in\{1,2\}$. Note that the latter assumption implies that $\Delta x_i \rightarrow 0$ as $x_i \rightarrow 0$. 
The farthest you can go without this sort of assumption and linear systems is **Input-to-State Stability (ISS)**, where you treat the uncertainty $\Delta x_i$ as an input. In that case, you can show that if $\Delta x_i$ are bounded by some constant for all $t$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ converge asymptotically to a ball near the equilibrium.